# 1.4mb data crashing browser in angular http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-http

I have a service that does a http request and get around of 1.4mb of json data.

It makes my browser stop responding.  :(

```
MapService.measures(id).then(function (data){            
        console.log("Get Measures!");            
        $scope.measures = data;
    });
```

What should i do?

Comment: What type of HTTP request are you making? If you're using `$http`, you should be getting a promise and then not making a blocking call by waiting on the promise to complete. Whenever the main thread of interaction stops in an asynchronous call, it is almost always because you're acting like it's synchronous/waiting for it to complete.

Comment: You must be having `measures` and using `ng-repeat` directive to render input, correct? Other guess is request is taking too much time to complete..

Comment: Yes @PankajParkar! Im using `ng-repeat` to render

Comment: Don't do that, rather use paging or infinite scrolling feature and show limited record on view at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Pankaj Parkar said, the problem was to render these data. So, i did simple pagination and solved it.